# "have problems V-ing" such as "...Students have problems preparing for the IELTS test." Why is that?

Tags: gerunds

I don't know which page in the book "Practical English Usage" I can learn about the usage of "have problems V-ing".

I try to look this usage up in "Practical English Usage" (Michael Swan).

Because I do not understand a sentence like the following one.

> "Students find it so easy to blame others or complain about their difficult situation when they have problems preparing for the IELTS test."

The structure of the form "*have problems V-ing*" is not clear to me.

I hope somebody bring answers to these questions.

Is it correct to say

> "...*have problems* **of** *preparing* for the IELTS test."

or

> "...*have problems* **to** *prepare* for the IELTS test."?

or

> "...*have problems* **to** *preparing* for the IELTS test."?

What is the difference between those three sentences in meaning?

How do I look this usage up in "Practical English Usage" (Michael Swan)?

Comment: Ah! So your question is: where in my book can I learn about this usage?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Yes. You are right. I don't know which page in my book "Practical English Usage" I can learn about this usage. This book is like a dictionary. So I "look up" it. Am I wrong with the usage of "look up"?

Comment: No, you are not wrong. Look under _gerund_ or _gerund phrase._ (We would say "How do I look up something **in** the book.")

Comment: Did you find the references to _gerund_ or _gerund phrase_ in your book?

Comment: @P. E. Dant I have been reading entries on gerunds, ing and participles. So far, examples in this book I read are quite different from the form of "...have problems preparing for...". But I do not give up. I will let you know once I find the exact entry which explains well.

Comment: It may be that the word _in_ has been omitted from the expression "problems _**in**_ preparing for the IELTS test." Sometimes words are omitted in English, but we understand the usage as if they are there. We call this _ellipsis._ In your book, there may be an entry under the word _ellipsis._

Comment: You might find it easier to understand if rearranged as such: "They have problems when preparing for the IELTS test."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Linguists would say that "The noun *problems* may take a subjectless gerund-participle clause" as a complement; but that's not a *Why*, it's just a name for the fact that that is how we say it.

To say that *Students have problems preparing ...* means that students find some aspect of preparing difficult.

You may also speak of problems ***with*** preparing, but that usually means having some (unspecified) objection to *preparing* itself. And you may speak of problems ***in*** preparing, but that usually means problems of some (unspecified) sort encountered while you are preparing.

You may encounter *problems **of** preparing*, but the preposition *of* introduces a specification of the problems, such as "the two problems of finding the error and repairing it".

Neither of your suggested alternatives with *to* is idiomatic.

Comment: I think of an example with "to" which is "...have approaches to gathering information". So when it come to the word "problem(s)", the form "have problem(s) V-ing" is appropriate.

Comment: @user9418 Yes: *approach* takes different sorts of complements than *problem* ... this is true of all words: there's no reliable formula, you just have to learn them word-by-word.

Comment: Before learning most of them word-by-word, I need to read them and identify them. Asking questions here help me start learning them in groups.

Answer (score 9):

And we can substitute a number of analogues for **problems**:

Do you have difficulty walking?

Do you have pain standing up?

Do you have trouble sleeping?

Do you have shortness-of-breath climbing stairs?

Do you have qualms doing that?

P.S. And they don't have to be problems:

Did you have a good time visiting them?

Do you like eating there?

Do you miss going there?